# Vue JS fat arrow method does not bind Vue instance

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6

Hi I am trying to use a fat arrow function as a method in a `vuex` component file:

```
methods : {
    method_1 : () => {console.log(this)}
}
```

`this` returns undefined, though if I use a `function() { console.log(this) }` it returns the current vue instance.

Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the `this` keyword works differently in classic function and arrow functions.

Vue.js assumes you will use a classic function so they can control what is the value of `this` (which is the Vue instance)

What you need to do is either:

```js
method_1 : function() { console.log(this) }
```

or

```js
method_1() { console.log(this) }
```

but you cannot use an arrow function if you need the `this` keyword